# How can i retrieve the thumbnails of a video from an android device in a Delphi 10.3 platform?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In a mobile app developed under Delphi 10.3, i want to display the thumbnail of the video i'm picking from the local storage of the device. Can anyone share a sample code that does this in Delphi.

Edited as per @Dave Nottage suggestion.
Now all i need is a way to acquire the absolute path of the picked video file.

```
procedure TForm1.OpenFileSelector(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>;
                                       const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);

var
  Intent: JIntent;

begin
  FMessageSubscriptionID := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification,
                                                                               HandleActivityMessage);
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_PICK);
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('video/*'));
  Intent.setAction(TjIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
  Tandroidhelper.Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent,0);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
//-----------------------------

procedure TForm1.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const aMessage: TMessage);
// when message is received
begin
  if aMessage is TMessageResultNotification then
    HandleIntentAction(TMessageReceivedNotification(aMessage).Value);
end;

//-------------------------------------------
function TForm1.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
{code to get the details of the file selected from gallery}
  //============
  function LoadBitmapFromJBitmap(const ABitmap: TBitmap; const AJBitmap: JBitmap): Boolean;
  var
    LSurface: TBitmapSurface;
  begin
    LSurface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
    try
      Result := JBitmapToSurface(AJBitmap, LSurface);
      if Result then
        ABitmap.Assign(LSurface);
    finally
      LSurface.Free;
    end;
  end;
  //---------------
  procedure AssignVideoThumbnails(aPath: string);
  var
    LBitmap: JBitmap;
    LFileName: string;
  begin
   // LFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'SampleVideo.mp4'); {using the paramter aPath instead}
    LBitmap := TJThumbnailUtils.JavaClass.createVideoThumbnail(StringToJString(aPath), TJImages_Thumbnails.JavaClass.MICRO_KIND); // 96 x 96
    if Assigned(LBitmap) then
      LoadBitmapFromJBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, LBitmap);
  end;
  //============
var
  vURI: JString;
  vFilePath: string;
begin
  if Assigned(Data) then begin
    vURI := Data.getData.getPath;        //getPath returns URI path
    vFilePath := ????                    // I NEED THE ABSOLUTE PATH of the selected file here
    AssignVideoThumbnails(vFilePath);    
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you think it's a trivial thing?

Comment: @Olivier what do you think?

Comment: I think you won't find any Delphi code for that.

Comment: Can you let me know what the value for vURI looks like? i.e. convert it to a string and examine it in the debugger

Comment: Sure. There you go:    /external/video/media/1864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
uses
  System.IOUtils,
  Androidapi.JNI.Media, Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  FMX.Surfaces, FMX.Helpers.Android;

function LoadBitmapFromJBitmap(const ABitmap: TBitmap; const AJBitmap: JBitmap): Boolean;
var
  LSurface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  LSurface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    Result := JBitmapToSurface(AJBitmap, LSurface);
    if Result then
      ABitmap.Assign(LSurface);
  finally
    LSurface.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LBitmap: JBitmap;
  LFileName: string;
begin
  LFileName := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'SampleVideo.mp4');
  LBitmap := TJThumbnailUtils.JavaClass.createVideoThumbnail(StringToJString(LFileName), TJImages_Thumbnails.JavaClass.MICRO_KIND); // 96 x 96
  LoadBitmapFromJBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, LBitmap);
end;
```

I deployed a sample video using Deployment Manager to a remote path of `./assets/internal`, which in code equates to `TPath.GetDocumentsPath`.

`LoadBitmapFromJBitmap` does pretty much what it says: takes a `JBitmap` and puts it into a `TBitmap` :-)

Comment: Thanks @Dave Nottage, it worked. The only remaining problem i have left here is trying to get the absolute file path of the video i'm selecting from my gallery. I'm able to retrieve the URI path from JIntent once i pick the file but i cannot fetch the absolute local path necessary to feed "createVideoThumbnail" function you pinpointed above. Currently i'm extracting the content of the URI into a stream, then saving the stream into a local file and using the path of the latter. I'm assuming this is an overkill and there must be a way to get the absolute path of the picked file.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you're doing with the intent

Comment: ...or ask another question regarding obtaining the filename from the intent

Comment: Sure @Dave Nottage. I just edited the question and added the piece of code i'm working with. My app attempts to select a video from the device's gallery and tries to display it's respective thumbnail in an image control.